# Using Phonegap to load external URL in an iFrame (ChildBrowser plugin?)

Tags: cordova, iframe, webview, external, childbrowser

I have been trying to load an external URL (HTML file on a different web server) in an iFrame, so that it is contained between my applications header and bottom tab bar.

I have tried using the iFrame HTML5 element and attributes, but am seeing different behavior between different Android versions (2.2/2.3) and iOS versions.  Sometimes the content within the iFrame element will break out of the iFrame and my header/tab bar disappears.  Other versions will still open up a native web browser even if the URL is white listed.  Additionally I cannot set the PhonGap.plist setting to display all external URL's in a webview as the app also has some links from the same domain that need to open a native browser.

I saw a post here where someone modified the ChildBrowser plugin to accomplish this ( [Using IFRAME in HTML5 applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620577/using-iframe-in-html5-applications) ), but there is no reference to the code, or steps on how this was accomplished.  I cannot use the default ChildBrowser behavior since I need to display my header and tab bar as well.

Does anybody know how I can display the external URL in an iFrame for all versions?  Or does anyone know what steps need to be taken to modify the ChildBrowser plugin to accomplish this?

Any help would be greatly appreciate it as I have spent many hours on this.